# Managing Place Instances in Roblox

Tags: roblox

So, apparently Roblox now has a way to [Teleport players between places](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=TeleportService_Guide).

That's great, but for the game I have in mind I need to have very fine-grained control over which players are let into which servers (or as Roblox seems to call them, "place instances"). How can I explicitly teleport a player or group of players to a new place instance with no other players in it?

Answer (score 2):

You can find the relevant article on the wiki [here](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=Dynamic_place_creation_and_saving)

Here is an example code:

```
local AssetService = Game:GetService(“AssetService”)
local TeleportService = Game:GetService("TeleportService")

local NewPlaceName = "New place #: " .. math.random() * 100
local NewPlaceId = AssetService:CreatePlaceAsync(NewPlaceName , [ID of template] )

for i,Player in ipairs(Game.Players:GetPlayers()) do
    TeleportService:Teleport(NewPlaceId , Player)   
end
```

The code will make a new instance from an template with the id [*[ID of template]*](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=Dynamic_place_creation_and_saving#Adding_a_template_place) and then send all players in the current game to that instance.

You can get more control by using the [DataStore](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=Data_store) (as seen in [example](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=Dynamic_place_creation_and_saving#Lobby%3a_Create.2FTeleport_To_Personal_Place_Pad))

Comment: Hmm, that's an interesting solution. So you're saying I should create a new place for every server I want to run, and manage them with Datastores?

Comment: @Ajedi32 If you want to have full control over which players are in what server. You should use the DataStore to keep track on which players are in which servers, and then reuse empty ones. Remember that if a place goes empty it resets unless you use the save function.

Comment: No, that's worst practice. You should use TeleportService instead with ReserveServer.

Answer (score 2):

Try making a Reserve Server. Reserve servers are generated to lock players out and hide the server, players can only join the server when the script you have made teleported them to the place it is running with the code it generated.

https://developer.roblox.com/api-reference/function/TeleportService/ReserveServer

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use TeleportService's ReserveServer function. The code might be clumped up, but read the code comments.

```lua
local TeleportService = game:GetService("TeleportService")
function ReserveServerAndTeleportParty(players)
    local reservedServer = TeleportService:ReserveServer(--[[Game's place ID]])
    TeleportService:TeleportToPrivateServer(00000000--[[Enter what you entered in the ReserveServer Function]],
        reservedServer,
        players,
        --[[From this point, everything is optional in this TeleportToPrivateServer function]]
        "Spawnpoint name for players to spawn at",
        "Teleport data",
        Instance.new("ScreenGui")--[[Custom loading screen]])
end
ReserveServerAndTeleportParty()
```

Answer (score 0):

When all players load into the place the maximum amount of players in the server will need to always equal to the number of players in the server so that the server is always full.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34622110)